# Optimizing a set comprehension in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I'm trying to optimize a Python program for speed.  After looking at my CProfiler dump, I find the bottleneck is in a set comprehension which appears as a call to `<setcomp>`. The relevant line of code is:

`mySet = {foo['bar'] for foo in long_list if foo['baz'] == special}`

Some more information which may be helpful:

- The resulting `mySet` is always small, between 0-10 elements.
- `long_list` is almost always very long (thousands of elements).
- `special` foo in `long_list`, what we are using to construct the set, are a small subset of `long_list` (tens or hundreds of elements, i.e., 1%-10% of all `foo` in `long_list`).

How should I optimize for speed?

- Pare down `long_list` to just the `special` ones before using the set comprehension?  If so, how can this be done quickly?
- Get rid of the set comprehension altogether?  Given the scenario (long list, 10% special ones, < 10 unique values that need to be fished out), what's the right algorithm/data structure?

It looks like it's even slower if we first pare down `long_list` with a list comprehension:

```
>>> mysetup='import random\nx = range(10)\nlonglist = [random.choice(x) for p in range(100000)]'
>>> stmt1 = 'myset = {item for item in longlist if item < 3}'
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt1, setup=mysetup, number=1000) 
3.17
>>> stmt2 = 'shortlist = [x for x in longlist if x < 3]\nmyset={x for x in shortlist}'
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt2, setup=mysetup, number=1000) 
3.86
```

Comment: Where do you get the list from? Maybe you could build your set during the build of the list?

Comment: Presumably you're doing the set comprehension multiple times on the same list (or at least a slightly modified version). It would be helpful to know how the iterations relate to one another.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat The `long_list` changes as we parse a long file; we have to do the set comprehension many times because the list changes.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat the changes are either adding an element to the `long_list` or taking away an element.  We generally will have to do the set comprehension every 100 changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep the result of the comprehension up to date as the list changes. Initialize a `collections.Counter` keyed on `bar` values, representing the number of special elements in the list with that `bar` value. To remove a value to the list, check whether it's special and if so decrement the counter. If that decrement drops the value to zero, remove the key from the `Counter`. To add a value to the list, check whether it's special and if so increment the counter. If `special` may take on multiple values, then keep one counter per possibility.

Comment: Thanks David, I will give this a whirl and report back.